# Reopen request: What characterizes My Chemical Romance's music?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, votes

[What characterizes My Chemical Romance's music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114546/what-characterizes-my-chemical-romances-music) was originally posted as "I don't really know how to phrase this but I'll try, Does anyone know what key most MCR songs are in?" and closed.

I've rewritten the question to be consistent with other questions on the site — a list is given in [I want to start a series of questions on how to compose a song from x popular genre. May I?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/i-want-to-start-a-series-of-questions-on-how-to-compose-a-song-from-x-popular-ge/3581#3581).

Comment: I still think it's kind of broad. MCR does have it's own sound, but we can pick it apart for days and days just like any other group.

Comment: @Dom We have been consistent in allowing this type of question. It's no more broad that the others in my (linked) list. For example: [Country music elements](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30364/country-music-elements) and [What musical tropes make sci-fi music recognizable?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15788/what-musical-tropes-make-sci-fi-music-recognizable).

Comment: Several answers in both say "This is a very broad topic" which kind of hints at the problem displayed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was reopened. Posting an answer so it's clear the issue is closed.